# The use of the primitive r:eval in NetLogo 6.2

Tags: netlogo

I would like to use the R extension within NetLogo 6.2

However when using the primitive r:eval the following message "Keyword expected" appears

The simple code used:

```
extensions [r]
r: eval "x <- seq (1.10)"
show r: get "x"
```

Can anyone help me understand this message?

Thanks all

Comment: In NetLogo, extension primitives must be written immediately after the colon, so `r:eval` not `r: eval`.  They are basically considered a single term, and the space makes NetLogo think you're moving on to something else.

Comment: Thanks! Resolved :)